# Gulp task apply uglify if file in pipe is javascript

Tags: javascript, pipe, task, gulp

I want to check if the file in the pipe is `.js` or not (it could be `.map`, `.html`, ...). And if so, uglifying it before copying it in the correct path.

ʕ •́؈•̀) I've try something like this (which not working):

#### gulpfile.js

```
gulp.src(current + '/**/*', {base: current})
.pipe($.tap(function (file) {
    if (path.extname(file.path) === '.js') {
        return gulp.src(file.path)
        .pipe($.uglify());
    }
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/' + name));
```

But for now, the uglify seems to do nothing...

Is anyone have a clue on how to do this ? (╥﹏╥)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using plugins there is one called gulp-filter that does what you're asking for.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter

It would probably look something like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // create filter instance inside task function
    var jsfilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', {restore: true});
    return gulp.src(current + '/**/*', {base: current})
        // filter a subset of the files 
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        // run them through a plugin 
        .pipe($.uglify())
        // bring back the previously filtered out files (optional) 
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/' + name));
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need ! And the `restore` is an essentiel part of the answer. Thank you!

Comment: The API has changed somewhat.  Now you must indicate that a filter is restorable, and restore is no longer a function.

`var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', { restore: true })`
...
`.pipe(jsFilter.restore)`

.

Answer (score 0):

try using gulp-filter

something like

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var jsFilter = filter('**/*.js');

gulp.src('*/*')
.pipe(jsFilter)
.pipe(uglify)
```